# Compare records value with each others

Tags: text-processing, awk

Consider the below file:

```
foo,boo,900
foo,boo,900
foo,boo,850
```

I need to compare the a field (`$3`) with the next record, if the difference is equal or more than 50, then print the record.

i.e from the sample above, `$3` from second record - `$3` from the third record = 50, then the output would be:

```
foo,boo,850
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `awk`

```
awk -F"," 'NR != 1 { if ((x - $3) >= 50) print $0; } { x = $3 }' file
```

and this one if you don't want to print row if filed `$1` changed:

```
awk -F"," 'NR != 1 { if ($1 == fc && (x - $3) >= 50) print $0; } { x = $3; fc = $1; }' file
```

Comment: It is worked, thank you, but I have one more question, how can I deny the action in case the first field `$1` changed.
in case of the following: 
`Record 1: foo,boo,900
 Record 2: boo,foo,850` 

in this case I don't want it to be printed out.

Comment: If field 1 differs from next row field 1?

Comment: yes, and problem solved by your answer.